# How to solve jspdf name conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using different `jsPDF` libraries in my react app like below:

For table `HTML` exports:

```js
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import "jspdf-autotable";
```

For `SVG` to `PDF` exports:

```js
const svg2pdf = require('svg2pdf.js');
const jsPDF = require('jspdf-yworks');
```

Both `jsPDF` and `jspdf-yworks` use the same name for creating `jsPDF object` like;

```js
const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [width, height]);
```

Is there any solution for the name conflict?

Thanks

Comment: why not simply change the const var name to jsPDF2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default import name e.g `import {default as jsPDFautotable} from 'jspdf'`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably using `const jsPDFyWorks = require('jspdf-yworks')`.

But note that you might be able to use yworks jspdf for autotable as well by utilizing the new applyPlugin method.

```
const jsPDF = require('jspdf-yworks')
const { applyplugin } = require('jspdf-autotable')
applyPlugin(jsPDF)

const doc = new jsPDF()
doc.autoTable({/*  options */})
```